# Nested liferay-ui:panel-container

Tags: liferay, jsp-tags, taglib, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 and need collapsible(!) `<liferay-ui:panel-container>`s to be nested (at least 2 layers deep).

I tried

```
<liferay-ui:panel-container extended="true" id="outerPanelContainer">
    <liferay-ui:panel collapsible="true" title="outer panel">
        outer content
        <liferay-ui:panel-container extended="true" id="innerPanelContainer">
            <liferay-ui:panel collapsible="true" title="inner panel">
                inner content
            </liferay-ui:panel>
        </liferay-ui:panel-container>
    </liferay-ui:panel>
</liferay-ui:panel-container>
```

but I get 2 "panels" that are not collapsible, as well as the outer panel not looking like a panel.

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

edit: Removing the inner container tag solves part of the problem: The panels are collapsible again, but this also removes the "[+]" and "[-]" icons on them, so the user does not get a visual clue that they're collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me, or I don't understand what do yout want to achieve, see screenshot:

[image]